# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-

Tags: javascript, go, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I have created an API using Go. It's working fine in postman but not when consumed using javascript. When I post request using javascript I'm getting an error saying that Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to null.

go API code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Calculate struct {
    Operand1  string   `json:"Operand1,omitempty"`
    Operand2 string   `json:"Operand2,omitempty"`
    Operator  string   `json:"Operator,omitempty"`
}

type Answer struct {
    Res string  `json:"Res,omitempty"`
}


func do_Calculation(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var cal Calculate
    var ans Answer
    fmt.Println("Request Reached")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&cal)
    // my stuff
    // res := do_Operations(convertToFloat(cal.Operand1),convertToFloat(cal.Operand2),cal.Operator)
    // ans = Answer{Res: floattostrwithprec(res, 4)}
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(ans)
}



// main function to boot up everything
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/calculate", do_Calculation).Methods("POST")
    fmt.Println("Server online at port :8000")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

javascript code:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "Operand1": "2.6",
  "Operand2": "2.4",
  "Operator": "+"
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/calculate");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(data);
```

error:

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/calculate: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of
>   requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the
>   withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338485/how-to-post-a-json-request-and-recieve-json-response-to-go-server-go-language). Post man is smart enough to add missing headers for you. But in code you have to add it by yourself

Comment: I have copied same the code from Post man but when I run in console I'm getting error

Comment: what error ? post it here the error you are getting

Comment: OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/calculate 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous) @ VM44:21
calci.html:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8000/calculate: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.

Comment: This is a VERY good question. Please upvote. Since postman normally does not do a preflight request things are perfectly fine in postman but fail when used from javascript for example.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are setting xhr request with credentials to true. It is a security loop hole to allow cross origin request for all domains using wild card `*`. So add `http://localhost:8000/` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/calculate");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(data);
```

Also in header in go lang code allow for `http://localhost:8000`:

```
func do_Calculation(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var cal Calculate
    var ans Answer
    fmt.Println("Request Reached")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&cal)
    // my stuff
    // res := do_Operations(convertToFloat(cal.Operand1),convertToFloat(cal.Operand2),cal.Operator)
    // ans = Answer{Res: floattostrwithprec(res, 4)}
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(ans)
}
```

Comment: calci.js:73 OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/calculate 405 (Method Not Allowed)
UserAction @ calci.js:73
(anonymous) @ calci.js:80
calci.html:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8000/calculate: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.


I'm getting this error

Comment: have you tried my code for both javascript and go. You should remove wildcard from `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: I have tried your code but i didnt get ans.
how to remove wildcards??

Comment: I have already removed wildcard and added the host `localhost` along with port number in the `access-control-allow-origin` header

Comment: Try using curl if it works. Use this `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"Operand1": "2.6", "Operand2": "2.4", "Operator": "+"}' http://localhost:8000/calculate`. Everything is working in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

A preflight request is a request to the server BEFORE the actual GET/POST/PUT/etc. It is of type OPTIONS to check if cross origin is allowed or not. Your server obviously does not implement a OPTIONS call as it says in your javascript error: `OPTIONS localhost:8000/calculate 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Since this is an extra request with method OPTIONS it will never arrive in `do_Calculation` handler. So you cannot fix the problem there.

What you have to do is register a global handler `/` of type OPTIONS and return the correct header information in there.

If you are using gin or gorilla or another router they might have an easy way of setting up such a handler. If you do not use a special router or want to do it manually, check [here](https://husobee.github.io/golang/cors/2015/09/26/cors.html) for what headers are expected by an OPTIONS call.

In Javascript I don't think you have to set any special headers but I wouldn't bet on it. Last time I implemented this I only implemented the go server side.

I used it with gin and simply had to use the following code:

```
CORSHandler = cors.New(cors.Config{
    AllowAllOrigins:  true,
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "Content-Length", "Content-Type"},
    AllowCredentials: false,
    MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
})
router.Use(CORSHandler)
```

Comment: any news on this Priya? Anything I can help?